# Is it possible to link my blogger account to my GooglePlus Company Page

Tags: google, blogger, google-plus

I updated my users Google login to a GooglePlus account, at the same I created a GooglePlus page for my (1 man) company. As I understand it I have just one google plus account, but that account lets me create multiple pages for companies, brands.

At this point the company page had my youtube videos I'd created for the company Youtube page, my own google plus page didn't really have anything. Then I have a company blog created using blogger.com a number of years ago and I decided to link this to my Google Plus account.

The problem is that I want to invite my customers to my Google Plus page, and it seems sensible to invite them to the company page rather than my own page. However when I post new entries on the blog they only get displayed on my own page not the company page, this doesn't make much sense because customers adding company page to their circle would want to see blog posts.

Have I misunderstood this, here are links to make it clearer

http://blog.jthink.net/ (blog)

https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/103554086121439078551/+JthinkNet2/posts (company page)

https://plus.google.com/104151123173952852147/posts (my posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2677294?hl=en

If you are using an older version of blogger, you're going to need to update your blog in order to connect to Google+. There are links to instructions on how to update your blog within that support article too.

Comment: Oh thanks, I think what happened was my page didnt exist when I converted by blog so there was no option to link to page then I didn't think of looking at Google+ tab with blogger again.